# Design of a system with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a producer-thread that takes a request from a queue. The requests in the queue are corresponding to many producer-threads dynamically starting and getting enqueued. When producer-thread deals with these requests, it places the response in a global buffer(global simple hashmap, not concurrent). Currently, my threads read the response using their IDs and busy wait until they get response.

- I do not know number of consumer-threads that may start. It is dynamic, based on requests from user.
- The global hashmap pairs unique id corresponding to thread with response. Each consumer-thread reads the hashmap for it's own it and removes it once available. Do I need a concurrent hashmap here? Producer will put result just once for each ID and consumer just removes and goes away forever.
- My threads busy wait for response. What's the best way to make them wait? How do I wait and notify in such scenario?

```java
// consumer thread
while(!globalBuffer.get(key)){
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
return globalBuffer.remove(key);
```

Comment: Instead of a global Buffer, have you considered using [Futures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to wait for a result?

Comment: @Fildor Can you give an example, how that can be used in given context? Can one thread notify just one another thread that result it ready?

Comment: And instead of using Threads, have you considered using an ExecutorService with a thread pool?

Comment: @user268396 I'm pretty new. So, I am just using a basic setup with threads, which looks like is a poor implementation.

Comment: @MaxSteel: if you have a `Futurure` you can call `get()` to do a blocking wait on its completion. Better yet, if you have some kind of observable/promise/monad type you can use continuations to automatically resume on completion so you do even need to do a blocking wait.

Comment: @user268396 What do you mean by observable/promise/monad. Sorry I didn't get this.

Comment: Just google it ... http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/ , http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html , https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/java-8-concurrency-tutorial/

Comment: @Fildor Would it be possible ti use CompletableFuture for multiple thread scenario like I mentioned?

Comment: @Maxsteel well these are concepts introduced to Java (mostly) from different languages, but basically they allow a nicer way to compose asynchronous operations with control flow & error handling. You should probably take the time to read up on them, because the background reading material should provide a ton of inspiration for how to tackle your problem in the best way.

Comment: I think: why use threads if the code is blocking? This looks like a better scenario for workflows or events.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Because an API call starts a thread and goes about to handle other requests.

Comment: "Would it be possible ti use CompletableFuture for multiple thread scenario" - without knowing your overall design, it is hard to give advice. If you really need multiple Threads to wait for a result, then this smells like you'd be better off with an Event-based approach to me. That means: Threads register to be notified, when a result is ready all registered entities would be notified of that. (= a method will be called on them) But I fear that the concept of threads is misleading you somehow.

Comment: @Maxsteel if your code is blocking as it need to wait the end of some staff done in a different thread, you're loosing all advantages of thread parallelism. That's why I suggested to introduce a different design approach, in order to avoid blocking code.